# arranging data from database using css

Tags: mysql, sql, css, mysqli

I am printing data from database using sql query, however when i get the output i am not getting it in the desired form.

Part of the code is

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM abc where id='".$a."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
{
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='dd' style='width:600px; padding-left:15px;'>";
                echo "<div class='col-lg-3' style='font-size:medium;'>";
                    echo  $row1['name'];
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";  
        }
}
```

output that i am getting is

```
q
w
e
r
```

however i wish to get out in the form

```
q  w  e
r  t  y
u  u  u
```

would appreciate any help

Comment: Show the generated HTML preferably in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try this- 
With the help of **UI & LI** html tag you can do... Sweet & simple code for you :)..

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM abc where id='".$a."'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
    {
        echo "<div class='list'>";
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

               echo  "<li>".$row1['name']"</li>"; 
            }
       echo "</ul>";
      echo "</div>";  
    }
```

**CSS -**

```
div.list{
   display:block;
   width:300px;
}

div.list ui{
   width:100%;
}

div.list ui li{
   float:left;
   width:33.333%;
   list-style-type:none;
}
```

Demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzqxb3xz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Can be accomplished by `CSS Float` property , on every 4th element we clear the `float`

```
$counter = 0;

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
   $counter++;

   $divstyle= 'clear:both';

   if($counter % 4 == 0){
      $divstyle= 'float:left';
   }

        echo "<div class='dd' style='width:600px; padding-left:15px;$divstyle;'>";
            echo "<div class='col-lg-3' style='font-size:medium;'>";
                echo  $row1['name'];
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";  
 }
```